# How to download and then use the file in the same tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I'm new using Tcl and I have the following script:

```
proc prepare_xml {pdb_id} {

    set filename [exec wget ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/msd/sifts/xml/$pdb_id.xml.gz]  

    set filename_unzip [exec gunzip "$pdb_id.xml.gz"]

    set ready_xml [exec sed -i  "/entry /c\<entry>" "$pdb_id.xml"]

    return $ready_xml
}
```

The expected output is the file "filename" uncompress and modified. However, when I execute it the first time, it only downloads the file and it does not uncompress it. If I execute it for a second time, I obtained the expected output and a second copy of the original downloaded file.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried with after and vwait commands but it doesn't work.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure as you're not describing whether any errors are thrown (that'd be the only reason for the code to not run to completion), but I'd expect something like this to be the right approach:

```
proc prepare_xml {pdb_id} {
    # Double quotes on next line just because of Stack Overflow highlighter
    set url "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/msd/sifts/xml/$pdb_id.xml.gz"
    set file $pdb_id.xml
    append sedcode {/entry /} "c\\\n" {<entry>}
    exec wget -q -O - $url | gunzip -c | sed $sedcode > $file
    return $file
}
```

Firstly, I'm keeping complicated bits in (local) variables to stop the `exec` line from getting too long. Secondly, I've put all the subprocesses together in the one pipeline. Thirdly, I'm using `-q` and `-O -` with `wget`, and `-c` with `gunzip`; look up what they do if you don't understand them. Fourthly, I've put the scriptlet for `sed` in braces where possible to stop there from being trouble with backslashes, but I've used `append` and a non-backslashed section to make the pattern because the syntax of `c` in sed is *downright weird* (it needs a backslash-newline sequence immediately after on at least some platforms…)

---

I'd *actually* use native Tcl code to extract and transform the data if I was doing it for me, but that's a rather larger change.